# All the columns are in one column

Tags: python, pandas

All I did was to import libraries and read the data. This is what I get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 181691 entries, 0 to 181690
Data columns (total 1 columns):
eventid,iyear,imonth,iday,approxdate,extended,resolution,country,country_txt,region,region_txt,provstate,city,latitude,longitude,specificity,vicinity,location,summary,crit1,crit2,crit3,doubtterr,alternative,alternative_txt,multiple,success,suicide,attacktype1,attacktype1_txt,attacktype2,attacktype2_txt,attacktype3,attacktype3_txt,targtype1,targtype1_txt,targsubtype1,targsubtype1_txt,corp1,target1,natlty1,natlty1_txt,targtype2,targtype2_txt,targsubtype2,targsubtype2_txt,corp2,target2,natlty2,natlty2_txt,targtype3,targtype3_txt,targsubtype3,targsubtype3_txt,corp3,target3,natlty3,natlty3_txt,gname,gsubname,gname2,gsubname2,gname3,gsubname3,motive,guncertain1,guncertain2,guncertain3,individual,nperps,nperpcap,claimed,claimmode,claimmode_txt,claim2,claimmode2,claimmode2_txt,claim3,claimmode3,claimmode3_txt,compclaim,weaptype1,weaptype1_txt,weapsubtype1,weapsubtype1_txt,weaptype2,weaptype2_txt,weapsubtype2,weapsubtype2_txt,weaptype3,weaptype3_txt,weapsubtype3,weapsubtype3_txt,weaptype4,weaptype4_txt,weapsubtype4,weapsubtype4_txt,weapdetail,nkill,nkillus,nkillter,nwound,nwoundus,nwoundte,property,propextent,propextent_txt,propvalue,propcomment,ishostkid,nhostkid,nhostkidus,nhours,ndays,divert,kidhijcountry,ransom,ransomamt,ransomamtus,ransompaid,ransompaidus,ransomnote,hostkidoutcome,hostkidoutcome_txt,nreleased,addnotes,scite1,scite2,scite3,dbsource,INT_LOG,INT_IDEO,INT_MISC,INT_ANY,related    181691 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
```

Why did this happen and how can I fix it?

Please help.

Comment: Do you mind providing information about the how did you read the dataframe?

Comment: data = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/gtd/globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv", "encoding='ISO-8859-1")

Comment: You should probably read stackoverflow's [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article. Notably: _DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text._

Comment: Oh, thank you. I am new to these things, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are just missing the separator.

```
data = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/gtd/globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv", encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=",")
```

Comment: I am getting this error:


TypeError: parser_f() got multiple values for argument 'sep'

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote but my reputation is under 15, sorry.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct so it is not searchable as open any more.